# how to cast class from object by method invoke ( ClassCastException )

Tags: java, android

I have Main apk and Sub apk(actually sub apk is kind of library)
And both of them have same arr file by library

Main App loads "MyClassInterface" class from sub app by dexclassloader
becuase Main App has sub apk file at assets folder

And "getMyClassInstance" method of "MyClassInterface" class return MyClass instance by method invoke
So, What I want is such as

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) methodGetMyClass.invoke(object);
myClass.getName();
```

but ClassCastExetion here like following log
Is it impossible ? or if not, how can I cast class ?

```
System.err java.lang.ClassCastException:com.example.library.MyClass cannot be cast to com.example.libary.MyClass
System.err at com.example.woosuk.mainapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
System.err at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
System.err at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
System.err at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
System.err at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
System.err at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
System.err at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
System.err at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
System.err at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
System.err at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
System.err at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

--------------------main app-----------------------------

```
DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader("data/data/com.example.woosuk.mainapplication/sub.apk", "", null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
try {
    Class<?> _class = dexClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.woosuk.subapplication.MyClassInterface");
    Object object = _class.newInstance();

    Method methodGetIntValue = _class.getMethod("getIntValue");
    Log.e("TEST", "getIntValue return " + methodGetIntValue.invoke(object));//working fine

    Method methodGetMyClass = _class.getMethod("getMyClassInstance");
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) methodMyClass.invoke(object);//ClassCastException!!!!!
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

--------------------sub app-------------------------------

```
public class MyClassInterface {

    public MyClass getMyClassInstance() {
        return new MyClass(99, "test");
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return 99;
    }
}
```

---------------------MyClass at Library --------------

```
package com.example.library;
public class MyClass {

    private int version;
    private String name;

    public MyClass(int version, String name) {
        this.version = version;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Github : https://github.com/woosuk0410

Library : https://github.com/woosuk0410/Library

SubApp : https://github.com/woosuk0410/SubApplication

MainApp : https://github.com/woosuk0410/MainApplication

Same quetion with [how to cast class from method invoke by dexclassloader ( ClassCastException )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974566/how-to-cast-class-from-method-invoke-by-dexclassloader-classcastexception)

Comment: change `_class.getMethod("getMyClass");` to `_class.getMethod("getMyClassInstance");`

Comment: Thanks, changed !

Comment: was this necessary? If so it should be added to the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of you're not use the same ClassLoader to load this two Classes.

Please try to use `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` instead of `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`